# Unknown android device connecting to my wireless router even after changing wifi key several times

Tags: network, wifi, network-access-control

An unknown android device is connecting to my wireless router even after changing the wifi key several times.
How is this possible?
My router admin page doesn't have a password set.
Even though how is it possible to access the admin page before connecting to the wifi.

Comment: What type of encryption is your network using? If it's WEP it can be easily circumvented with many apps freely available in the app store. You should try to use WPA2 and a long, complex password.

Comment: Make sure your public IP isn't forwarded to the internal admin page. If you have your public IP forwarded to the router admin page, your WiFi password is basically giving itself away

Comment: @DanielE encryption is WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK AES, password is pretty complex with numbers letters and special chars

Comment: @Veroxi What is a public IP?

Comment: A public IP is the one on the Internet side of your network. It is Internet wide publickly reachable and the target of about 20 attacks per day coming from any part of the world. [return] You have to secure this access 1st before plugging it to the wide Internet.

Comment: 1.) Turn off WPS if enabled
2.) Make sure you have WPA2-PSK AES with a complex password

Answer (score 1):

Yet another question asking for help that got unfairly downvoted by an anonymous coward who didn't bother to help. Upvoted and FTFY.

Anyway, now for the answer. You mentioned your router admin page isn't login protected. Rookie mistake, right off the bat. If the owner of the unknown device knows the manufacturer and model of your router, it becomes trivial to look up the config instructions for the router, navigate to the admin page, and change various settings, including the router key.

Intuitively, there should be a chicken-and-egg problem preventing access even if you have a setup like that: the unknown device doesn't have the router access info, so it has no way of getting on the network to access the admin page. However, this becomes a problem if your router allows open access through some misconfiguration (Veroxi's comment provides a good example).

I have no idea if your router supports MAC-address banning - if it does, you could see if you can find access information, find the MAC address of the offending device, and ban it.

Finally, as Daniel E. said, use a good encryption and authentication scheme. The modern standard is WPA2. In particular, stay away from WEP. Most modern routers will use WPA or WPA2 by default if you setup the router to require authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have wps turned off.

Wps is like a "secondary password" in form of a pin, that allow in many cases WPA passphrase crack.

@Rahul Please ensure that you have wps turned off under your advanced Wifi config in routers webAdmin pannel.

Comment: It that all you have to do to prevent someone from accessing your wifi? And why would this help? (Just trying to help improve your answer)

Comment: @dolpsdw can you explain why?